# Request Method showing OPTIONS instead of POST

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm working a project where I will upload a file to s3. I'm using XMLHttpRequest to submit a post request to s3 and its giving me a 403 Forbidden status. When I check the request I made in my firebug its showing a "Request Method: OPTIONS" and its suppose to be a POST request.

Here is my code below:

```
function GetXmlHttpObject () {

     var xmlHttp = null;

     try {
       // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari, IE 7+
       xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (e) {
       // Internet Explorer - old IE - prior to version 7
       try {
          xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (e) {
          xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     }

     return xmlHttp;
    }

function uploadFile() {
    console.log(AWSAccessKeyId);
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();

    var key = "events/" + (new Date).getTime() + '-' + file.name;

    fd.append('key', key);
    fd.append('acl', 'public-read'); 
    fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);      
    fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', AWSAccessKeyId);
    fd.append('policy', policyBase64)
    fd.append('signature', signature);

    fd.append("file",file);

    var xhr = GetXmlHttpObject();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open('POST', 'https://'+bucket+'.s3.amazonaws.com/', true); //MUST BE LAST LINE BEFORE YOU SEND 
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");
    xhr.send(fd);
  }
```

I'm stuck here. T__T.

Comment: And you have code that is setting up XMLHttpRequest objects for old IEs which this code will never work for.

Comment: You are also explicitly setting the Content-Type of the request, which you should NOT do in this case.

Comment: @epascarello, do you mean to say that the top code will not really work?

Comment: In IE9 and older it will definitely not work as the File API is not supported in those browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You are triggering a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). The browser is making an OPTIONS request to make sure it has permission (via CORS) to access the server before making the POST request.

You must configure your bucket to support CORS with preflighted requests [as described in Amazon's own documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors).

Comment: hmm, I don't have a access to the s3 account, they've only given me a temporary credentials. Actually I have an other code where I used the s3 browser based upload but it also kept on giving me an 403 Forbidden or access denied. Do you think this is the solution for my status 403?